# How to use python-code on any WordPress web-page

Tags: python, wordpress, plugins

**I have a requirement where i have to use my python project into WordPress web page, where i ask user for input in one tab than execute it and gives back the result on display on the web-page.**

I found one plugin for the same namely: "Create With Code". 
It worked pretty well, only challenge was to expose my code into third party website which i can not do.

Now i have started to create my own custom plugin to do the same.

***Could anyone suggest whether i am on a right track or is there any other secure straightforward way to achieve that.***

Comment: Try this once https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress

Comment: @HarshKhare thanks for suggestion, but it has its own challenges in order to implement.